# Regex to replace any character at a given position

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like to replace one single character to a different one, which is in a specific position in the string.
Example:

`This is a test string! Now comes a different one! And yet an another one to demonstrate what I want! Hello there! How can I achieve to replace all exclamation mark to point!`

I know that my character is on the 21<sup>st</sup> position, therefore I tried: `.{21}(.)\K(.*?\1)+`
The first capturing group has the character I want, and I can utilize \K to start from the last match. But then, how can I match the rest of the string?

The desired output would be:
`This is a test string. Now comes a different one. And yet an another one to demonstrate what I want. Hello there. How can I achieve to replace all exclamation mark to point.`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^.{21}\K.
```

Or, if there are line breaks,

```
(?s)^.{21}\K.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2yeTTO/1/)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a dotall modifier that makes `.` match line break chars, too
- `^` - start of string
- `.{21}` - any 21 chars
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `.`  - any one char.

Note that in many cases you may just use a group and backreference, `^(.{21}).` -> `$1<<YOUR_REPLACEMENT_STRING>>`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but I have to replace every single exclamation mark to a point (I have edited my original post and added the desired output).

Comment: @Attila You need to do that in two steps, without the support for an unlimited pattern length in lookbehinds it is not possible.